# SFTP Openssh configuration

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, sftp

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and today I installed sftp server using openssh for my server.
I followed the instructions on the internet, everything is good, they said I have to add this codes to sshd_config file:

```
Match group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

I did it and the sever can't connect with error from filezilla :"The software cause connection abort. Could not connect to server".
Tried in another computer with another version of filezilla and the result is same.
But, when I added that code into file ssh_config and deleted from sshd_config. The connection was work perfectly. Anyone here know why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that /home is accessible by sftp group (because by default it isn't).

If the sftp group doesn't work, make sure you're actually logging in with a key, you can first confirm it by using ssh from the terminal (or putty on windows)
`ssh -vvv login@hostname.com`

by default, as long as you're not using root account, you should be able to login without any issues.

the most interesting keys for basic setup are usually:
- `PubkeyAuthentication` to be able to login with keys (also needs `UsePAM yes`)
- `PermitRootLogin` if you want to login with root account
- `PasswordAuthentication` to allow/disallow using password auth

Comment: Hi. I added group and also added user to that group. I give the permission to home folder based on this code `$ sudo chmod 700 /home/sftpuser/`
maybe in my file doesn't have  `UsePAM yes` right?

Comment: if the sftpuser is normal system user, `UsePAM yes` is necessary for it to work. make sure the user has correctly set home dir in /etc/passwd. 
Fix the `ChrootDirectory` to use username in the path: `ChrootDirectory /home/%u`

Comment: I added password for sftpuser and I would like to make connecting using password, so should I add `PubkeyAuthentication yes  usePAM yes  PasswordAuthentication yes  ` to sshd_config ?

Comment: yes, but fix the ChrootDirectory, too. JUST `/home` is not ok

Comment: Good news, I found the problem, the problem is `chrootDirectory /home`. My sftp user is "bloom-sftp", if I edit that code like this `chroorDirectory /home/bloom-sftp` it will crash connection, but if I write only /home it work. Look like the folder bloom-sftp have not root permission right? I have already type this command `sudo chmod 700 /home/bloom-sftp/`

Comment: chmod 700 means the group won't have access, only the owner will have (owner and group of the directory contents can be seen with `ls -al` command) but yes, overall sounds like permissions issue